How to make a std::array at compile time where the element contains template arguments?
I am creating a completely compile-time SQL database as a learning project. The problem is I need to store X number of elements with different template arguments, but all the the same functionality for easy use. I would like to use an easy data structure as the other option is to generate a database class based on the tables, which, while doable, seems like lot of work.
I have a Table class and a Database class. The Table class takes a template argument CompileTimeString.
template<CompileTimeString TableName, CompileTimeString OtherData>
class Table
{
public:

    //...
};

In the database class, I want to store a std::array of tables. The issue is the table names vary.
class Database
{
public:

    template<CompileTimeString TableName, CompileTimeString OtherData>
    void add_table()
    {
        //construct a table and add it to the array
    }

    std::array<Table, 10> tables;
};

All of the tables are guaranteed to be known at compile time along with their names. CompileTimeString is just an abstraction for a const char[N] with some convenience features. I want to add tables by calling add_table<CompileTimeString("TableName"), CompileTimeString("OtherData")>(); The added tables should be stored into the tables array. All of this will be done at compile time.
Is there a way to accomplish what I am trying to do?
I tried variations of the following:
template<CompileTimeString... TableNames, DatabaseSchemaDescriptorPair... Descriptors>
std::array<Table<TableNames, Descriptors>..., 10> tables;

My goal is to learn template metaprogramming.

Table<name1> and Table<name2> are two different types; elements of an array (whether a C-style array or std::array) are all the same type. So there's a fundamental mismatch here.

@PeteBecker But is it not possible to store the names in a parameter pack? I can do something like this: template<CompileTimeString TableName, DatabaseSchemaDescriptorPair... Descriptors> const bool create_table() and access all Descriptors from create_table. Is a similar strategy not possible?

"The issue is the table names vary." -- More to the point, the issue is that the types vary.

@Eshy "But is it not possible to store the names in a parameter pack?" -- Yes, but that is irrelevant to your question. It is not possible to store different types as elements of a single array. For what you want, I think you would be better off removing the template from Table and making the table name a non-static member of Table. Or maybe polymorphism. Can't do more than guess because you asked for help with your approach instead of your real goal.

@JaMiT My goal is to learn template metaprogramming. Here I am creating a completely compile-time SQL database as a learning project. The problem is I need to store X number of elements with different template arguments (as you pointed out different types), but all the the same functionality for easy use. I would like to use an easy data structure as the other option is to generate a database class based on the tables, which, while doable, seems like lot of work.

We need a [mcve]

You could use std::tuple instead of std::array. But add_table()... no, functional programming doesn't work this way. All tables must be known at the moment when Database is defined (not even constructed). Start with something like template<class... Tables> class Database { ... }; using MyDatabase = Database<Table1, Table2, ...>;.

As already pointed out, the characteristic of metaprogramming is that all your functions need to be pure (stateful metaprogramming, SMP, are considered illegal by the standard). You also need to be aware of things at the data level and the type level. By CompileTimeString you have promoted your data to the type level, so what you are looking for is also an array at the type level, which is std::tuple. Think thoroughly through these two points and if you still have a question, edit the question to ask about it, and include your thought process.

@Eshy In the future, any information that improves your question should go in the question; information in the comments is subject to disappear at any moment. And the information that you are not locked into an array is useful. There is still one problem I see, though, before getting to an answer: "I want to add tables by calling add_table<CompileTimeString("TableName"), CompileTimeString("OtherData")>(); [...] this will be done at compile time." -- How do you plan to call a function at compile time? It's not impossible, maybe fixable, but I suspect this is a gaping hole in your plan.

From the point of view of the author of the Table and Database classes and class templates, we do not know how these structures are going to be used by the consumer of the code. Therefore we do not know how many tables or which kind of tables the database need to support.
As the tables are considered as different and unrelated types by the compiler, then this information must be provided to the Database at compile time by the consumer somehow. One way is to tell the Database using template parameters.
template<class... Tables>
class Database { 
    // ...
};

If the Database is going to manage these different tables, it needs to have some way to reference the different tables somehow. As the tables are considered unrelated types by the type system, a homogeneous container type such as std::array or std::vector will not work. We need a heterogeneous container type which we can specify at compile time. We can use std::tuple because each Table type is associated with exactly one table instance.
template<class... Tables>
class Database {
    // ...
    std::tuple<Tables...> tables;
};

To access the table at a specified index we can use std::get<Idx>(tables), where Idx is a compile time index.
If all the tables are unique we can specify the type of the table with std::get to access it as such std::get<Table1>(tables).
If we want to let users add new tables at compile time, we have to create a new Database type with all the previous tables and append a new table to it.
This can be achieved by a simple typedef.
template<class... Tables>
class Database {

    // ...

    template<class NewTable>
    using add_table = Database<Tables..., NewTable>;

    // or to specify the table template parameters
    // template<class... TableParameters>
    // using add_table = Database<Tables..., Table<TableParameters...>>;

    std::tuple<Tables...> tables;
};

Now as a user of the provided database library I can specify the database and tables however I want.
// I have 3 tables I want to put in the database

using MyDatabase = Database<>::add_table<Table1>::add_table<Table2>::add_table<Table3>;

// Or
// using MyDatabase = Database<>::add_table<Params1...>::add_table<Params2...>::add_table<Params3...>;

Or if I want to do it over multiple lines
using DbComp0 = Database<>;
using DbComp1 = DbComp0::add_table<Table1>;
using DbComp2 = DbComp1::add_table<Table2>;
using DbComp3 = DbComp2::add_table<Table3>;
using MyDatabase = DbComp3;

MyDatabase db;
// Add something to table 2
add_item_to_table(std::get<Table2>(db.tables), item);

